# Using atoi() and printing a string fail - C

Tags: c, visual-studio, printing, atoi

I want to write a program that it will read a couple of strings, convert one of them to an integer using the atoi() and then printing another.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 3

int main() {
    char Name[N][20], Sname[N][20], afm[N][5];
    int i = 0;
    char slash;
    int date, month, year;
    int afmi;

    while (1) {

        printf("Give a 5-digit number: ");
        gets(afm[i]);

        afmi = atoi(afm); //Converting the afm string to an integer

        if (afmi == 0) { /*Getting out of the while loop as soon as the afm                                                              string gets 0 as an input. */
            break;
        }

        printf("Give your name: ");
        gets(Name[i]);

        printf("Give your Surname: ");
        gets(Sname[i]);

        printf("Birth date: "); //dd/mm//yy format
        scanf("%d%c%d%c%d", &date, &slash, &month, &slash, &year);
        getchar();


        i++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= N+1; i++) {  /*Here i want to print all the names i have input, one under another*/ 
        printf("name: %s \n", Name);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So my problem is that it doesnt exit the while loop if i enter 0 as an input the second time i do the process. Moreover, it does not print the names correctly in the end... What can i do? (Take in consideration that i am an amateur :D)
Thank you for your help!

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("name: %s\n", Name[j]);
    }`

Comment: *Never* use the obsolete `gets`. Use at least `fgets`, and preferably `getline`

Comment: `afm[i]` cannot represent a null-terminated string of 5 characters!!! Change `afm[N][5]` to `afm[N][6]`.

Comment: `afmi = atoi(afm);` -->`afmi = atoi(afm[i]);`

Comment: Yes, again with the absurd byte-counting.  'Give a 5-digit number' should mean that no developer should go near any buffer smaller than [16].

Comment: for readability by us humans, please follow the guide line of:  `only one statement per line and at max only one variable declaration per statement.`   This also makes documenting the variables much easier, for instance when using `doxygen` for documentation

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf("%d%c%d%c%d", &date, &slash, &month, &slash, &year);` always check the returned value from `scanf()` to assure all the input/conversions were successful.

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient space for the string.  [@barak manos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1382251/barak-manos)

When the following code attempts to read 5 `char` into `afm[i]`, it invokes undefined behavior as a keyboard entry of 5 `char` like "abcde" and  <kbd>Enter</kbd>, attempts to store `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'d'`, `'e'`, `'\0'` into `afm[i]`.

```
// Bad code
#define N 3
char afm[N][5];
    printf("Give a 5-digit number: ");
    gets(afm[i]);
```

The above is a an example of the problem of using `gets()`, which is no longer standard in C11.

Instead use `fgets()`.

```
  printf("Give a 5-digit number: ");
  char buf[80];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOF();
  afmi = atoi(buf);  // or strtol() for better error handling.
```